# Set only maximum worker threads in ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(int workerThreads, int completionPortThreads)
```

The [SetMaxThreads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) method requires both worker threads and completion port threads to be set. Is there any way where I can set only max worker threads and let the Threadpool decide the completion port threads.

If there is no solution, is there a recommended value for port threads when workerThreads count is 6.

I am using this code to Queue SSIS packages from code which take about 10 to 20 seconds to execute.

System Info: 
[Intel Core i3-3220 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/65693/Intel-Core-i3-3220-Processor-3M-Cache-3_30-GHz) (Dual Core, 4 Threads)

Comment: You can call `GetMaxThreads` get current `completionPortThreads` value, and then set it back in `SetMaxThreads` method, so value will be the same as it was

Comment: Thank you. That should solve my problem. :)

Comment: SetMaxThreads() tends to be abused to work around a problem where tp threads are I/O bound.  Certainly likely when tinkering with SSIS.  In which case not also changing the max number of completion threads makes little sense.  All that it really does is tick off the DBA badly.

Comment: @HansPassant I have come across articles asking me not to set the threadpool max threads but not setting the max threads was slowing down my PC. Hopefully this will work, else need to create a custom thread pool for solving this issue. Thank you for the tip though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use GetMaxThreads to get current, and only change workerThreads..

```
//get value
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out maxWorker, out maxCompletionThreads);

//set only workerThreads
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(differentValue, maxCompletionThreads);
```